# How can I make sure that my javascript removes whitespace before adding "..."

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string variable that looks this:

> Årets upplaga av Storsjöcupen, en fotbollsturnering i Östersund för
>   ungdomar, fick en trist avrundning när anhängare till ett norskt
>   pojklag anklagades för att ha farit ut i rasistiska och
>   könsordskryddade tillmälen mot spelare i motståndarlag.

When my javascript is executed it turns the string to:

> Årets upplaga av Storsjöcupen, en fotbollsturnering i Östersund för
>   ungdomar, fick en trist avrundning när anhängare till ett norskt
>   pojklag ...

If you see the three "..." there is a space that I dont want to have.

I want it to be:

> pojklag...

My javascript looks like this:

```
  function TrimLength(text, maxLength) {
          text = $.trim(text);

          if (text.length > maxLength) {
              text = text.substring(0, maxLength - ellipsis.length)
              return text.substring(0, text.lastIndexOf(" ")) + ellipsis;
          }
          else
              return text;
      }
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function () {
          $(".text").each(function () {
              var text = $(this).text();
              $(this).text(TrimLength(text, 150));
          });
```

How can I make sure that the space gets removed?

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you aware that, if this is for display, you can get the same effect with just CSS?

Comment: I have tried it but it doesnt give same effect :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply change this line:

```
return text.substring(0, text.lastIndexOf(" ") - 1) + ellipsis;
```

Your code is finding the last space and removing everything after it.  Simply make the length passed to `substring` be one character less, and you'll remove the last space as well.

Comment: Note that (however unlikely) if there are no spaces in `text` then this will output `"..."`. (As would the OP's code.)

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
function trimLength( text, maxLength ) {
    text = $.trim( text );
    if( text.length <= maxLength )
        return text;
    return text
        .slice( 0, maxLength - ellipsis.length )
        .replace( /\s+\S*$/, '' )
        + ellipsis;
}
```

This should handle all of the cases mentioned in the other comments, including a string with no spaces in it, as well as a string with more than one consecutive space where it breaks.

Also, just as a suggestion, I took the liberty of changing the function name from `TrimLength` to `trimLength` because it is not a constructor. Idiomatic JavaScript begins constructor names with a capital letter and other functions and variables with a lowercase letter.

Comment: /\s*$/ is the regex you'd need.